# "Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row" trying to remove unused rows from my datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, delete-row

I'm grabbing data, sticking it into a `DataTable`, and displaying it in a `DataGridView` bound to that table. Im trying to make it so that data in the datatable that is not included in the current grab is deleted. I'm doing it as follows:

```
public void FillTable(DataTable table, IEnumerable<MyObject> readings)
{
    var currentReadingsNames = new List<string>();
    var lastParent = string.Empty;
    var index = 0;

    foreach (var reading in readings)
    {
        if (reading.ParentName != lastParent)
        {
            lastParent = reading.ParentName;
            index = 0;
        }
        LoadRow(table, reading, index++);
        currentReadingsNames.Add(MakeKey(reading));
    }

    //Iterate through the rows in our data table. If the row is not one we just loaded, get rid of it.
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (!currentReadingsNames.Contains(MakeKey(row["ParentID"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString())))
        {
            row.Delete();
        }
    }
    table.EndLoadData();
}
```

`MakeKey(reading)` and `MakeKey(properties)` returns a string I can use to identify my object two different ways. Assume that this works.

When I run this, I get:

> Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

I feel like I shouldn't be attempted to access a deleted row, because I only delete the row after I'm done looking at its values (the `parentID` and `ID` column). Does this behave differently than I am understanding? Any ideas why this is happening? If this code should work, maybe the error is somewhere else, but I haven't changed anything else so I would be surprised (I'm trying to add this deleting behavior).

Comment: Can you please post the FULL exception?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a filter for deleted rows as:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    if(row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted) 
    {     
       if (!currentReadingsNames.Contains(MakeKey(row["ParentID"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString())))
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing and it worked, it just seemed kinda hacky and I was trying to understand WHY I was still getting deleted rows, as this is the only place anywhere in code I am deleting anything, and I couldn't wrap my head around what was happening. But thank you regardless.